# Opening Linux file on Windows

Tags: linux

I'm learning about ray-tracing algorithms and I came across this [site.](http://eleni.mutantstargoat.com/portfolio/prj/rt.html)
At the bottom of the page there is an available download of source code. In the tar file there is an **rt** file.

How do I open this file? I mean, what is it? Is it a script or a C-compiled code? Anyway, is there a way to convert this to the original source code?

Any hint appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can always open any file with Notepad++. It will figure out line-ending conversions and display the file's intent. (In this case, you have a binary file, so it will look like garbage, but it is indeed the file that's been opened).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `rt` is a precompiled linux binary (see below).  The author included all of the compilation artifacts in the tar file, along with the source.

```
$ tar xf rt.tar  
$ file rayt/rt 
rayt/rt: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=3b7cd05d3123da4404969eb68d76ceb2858eeedd, not stripped
```

You can't really do much with it, although you could look into running [Ubuntu on Windows 10](http://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-and-canonical-partner-to-bring-ubuntu-to-windows-10/).  It uses [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), though, and that might not work with Microsoft's Ubuntu integration.

In that case, you might give something like [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) a try.  You could make a Linux VM.  Pick a distribution that contains SDL (CentOS 7 does.)

I was able to compile it on CentOS7 by just doing `g++ *.cc -lSDL`, although I had to change `#include <SDL.h>` to `#include <SDL/SDL.h>` in `rt.cc`.

Addendum:

SDL is also available on Windows and I noticed that `rt.cc` has some Windows code in it.  So you might be able to get this to compile directly on Windows.

Comment: So I can't convert it to something more readable? The reason I'm asking is because when I open it in PSPad, I see the binaries of course, but next to that there are the characters equivalent to the binary. And there is some C code. I'm just not able to read anything out of it.

Comment: `rayt/tr` is a binary.  You could disassemble it, but why not just read the source code under `rayt/src/`?

Comment: If you are trying to look at the *tar file*, then use 7zip, as suggested by RaulTheThinker.  My answer is specific to the files contained within.

Comment: For your curiosity, [this](http://pastebin.com/Tm68izi0) is what the binary looks like when made into something more readable.  It's 386 assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to unzip that file (or anything compatible with .tar really)
. There's a 'src' folder inside

Read about .tar:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)

> In computing, tar is a computer software utility for collecting many files into one archive file, often referred to as a tarball, for distribution or backup purposes. The name is derived from (t)ape (ar)chive, as it was originally developed to write data to sequential I/O devices with no file system of their own. The archive data sets created by tar contain various file system parameters, such as name, time stamps, ownership, file access permissions, and directory organization.

Comment: Please read the question again. I'm asking about the rt file.

Comment: "Anyway, is there a way to convert this to the original source code?" The source code is inside the file. Try using 7zip and you'll get the "**rayt**" folder with the "**src**" inside that and no "**rt**" file.